# Bundle Active but still shows - No services found (cxf)

Tags: spring-boot, soap, cxf, apache-felix, apache-servicemix

I have Spring Boot application and i want to deploy it on service mix as a bundle. The application is with soap services and i want to access them trough servicemix.

This is my pom:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.myorg.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<name>cxf-demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.bundlerepository</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>CXF</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Private-Package>com.myorg.cxf.cxfdemo*</Private-Package>
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.apache.felix.shell,             
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                        org.apache.felix.shell,
                        com.myorg.cxf.cxfdemo.service.MeterImpl,
                        org.springframework.boot,
                        com.myorg.cxf
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is the way i expose the service:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

@Autowired
private Bus bus;

@Bean
public Endpoint endpointMeter() {

    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, new MeterImpl());
    endpoint.publish("/Meter");
    return endpoint;
}}
```

This is my application properties:

```
server.port=8181
server.address=192.1.1.1
cxf.path=/cxf
```

Now when i start the program localy i can see my service that is active:
[image]

I had a lot of problems to pack it as a bundle but in the end i have got this:
[image]

So now when i am trying to access my services on service mix instead to see my service i am seeing No services found.

My question is: Did i made my bundle correct?
And why i can not see my service as active on service mix.